# Does the index notation of tensor require the same set of basis for each copy of V?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

According to Wikipedia, when defining tensor using tensor product, each copy of V(or V*) seems to use the same set of basis (or co-basis), but I feel it is ok to use different irrelevant basis for each copy of V and V*. More rigorous description of the question:

$$ T\in V\otimes\dotsb\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes\dotsb\otimes V^*$$

$$T = T^{i_1\dotsm i_p}_{j_1 \dotsm j_q} e^1_{i_1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes e^p_{i_p} \otimes \epsilon_1^{j_1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes \epsilon_q^{j_q} .$$

here $e^m_{i_m}$ is from the choosen set of basis of the mth copy of $V$, $\epsilon_n^{j_n}$ is from the choosen set of basis of the nth copy of $V^*$. These choosen basis from different copy of $V$ and $V^*$ are not related at all. (For comparison, the definition in Wikipedia seems to require all the choosen basis of $V$ are the same, and all the choosen basis of $V^*$ are its dual basis, the question is about removing this requirement)

Then does the above $T^{i_1\dotsm i_p}_{j_1 \dotsm j_q}$ still transform like a tensor when a given linear transform (and its dual linear transform) is applyied to the choosen basis of each V (and V*)?

Comment: Your notation is a bit off: $e_1\otimes e_1$ is a tensor of the sort you want ($q = 0$, $p = 2$, $T^{1,1} = 1$ and $T^{ij} = 0$ otherwise) but the first $e_1$ is the first element of an ordered basis for $V$, and the second $e_1$ is the first element of another ordered basis for $V$. Instead, let $\{\{e_i^k\}_{i=1}^n\}_{k=1}^p$ be the bases for $V$ and $\{\{\epsilon^j_l\}_{j=1}^n\}_{l=1}^q$ be the bases for $V^*$. Then you want to consider $$T = T^{i_1\dotsm i_p}_{j_1 \dotsm j_q} e^1_{i_1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes e^p_{i_p} \otimes \epsilon_1^{j_1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes \epsilon_q^{j_q}.$$

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese That was what I mean, $e_{i_p}$ means $e_{i_p}^p$, I think Wiki omit the upper p since it is already under i

Comment: That may be what you meant, but the point of my comment is that the notation you used in the question doesn't mean what you intended it to mean. Wikipedia doesn't omit upper indices. As you said, the basis for $V$ is the same for each copy of $V$, and the basis for $V^*$ is the same for each copy of $V^*$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for your suggestion , get your point now. I've put it into the new version.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important properties of tensors is that the set of all tensors of type $(r,s)$ at a point $P$ constitutes a vector space of dimension $n^{r+s}$. It is so because you can add two tensors at P and get a new tensor of the same type $(r,s)$ and you can multiply a tensor by a scalar or a constant and still yield a tensor of the same type.

With your proposed system this is no longer possible because you are not allowed to add tensors whose types are distinct. You need to complicate matters by introducing new types and add some transformations.

We would also like to be able to multiply the components of two tensors of types $(r_1,s_1)$ and $(r_2,s_2)$ to yield a tensor of type $(r_1+r_2, s_1+s_2)$. Again this will not be possible with your proposal without a profusion of new definitions and transformations.

Another important property of tensors is the invariance under contraction. We need stuff like

$$
\mathbf{a}\cdot(\nabla\times V)=\varepsilon^{ijk}\frac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^i}a_k
$$

to be invariant regardless of the underlying charts. Imagine the work needed to be put in if you expressed the $(0,2)$-tensor $V_{j|k}=\frac{\partial V_j}{\partial x^k}-\Gamma_{j\,\,\,k}^{\,\,m}V_m$ in random charts for each component.

Not to mention the profusion of complications dealing with differential forms and so on.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the question is more about: does the above $T^{i_1\dotsm i_p}_{j_1 \dotsm j_q}$ still transform like a tensor, i.e. one way to define tensor is seeing it as multi dimensional array who transform in a "tensor way".

Comment: The general definition of a tensor (at a point $P$ on a differentiable manifold) is based on the transformation between *a pair* of overlapping charts $(U_1,h_1),(U_2,h_2)$ with the respective coordinate functions related by $\bar{x}^j=\bar{x}^j(x^h)$ (where $x^j=u^j\circ h$ is a map $U\to \mathbb{R}$). For example $\overline T^{uv}_w=\frac{\partial\bar{x}^u}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial \bar{x}^v}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial {x}^k}{\partial \bar{x}^w}T^{ij}_k$. Clearly your proposed tensor concept needs an extended definition of "transformation" (among other things) and hence is not a tensor.